# How to convert a camelCased variable to lowercase with underscores in Notepad++ or IntelliJ using regular expressions

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, text, notepad++

I have to rename the toString output variables in several hundred files with many occurrences in each. In the most efficient way possible, how could I parse this text:

```
   .append(", myVariable=").append(myVariable)
   .append(", myOtherVariable=").append(myOtherVariable)
   .append(", mylowervariable=").append(myLowerVariable) // note the left is already lowercase
   .append(", myVarWithURL=").append(myVarWithURL);
```

and it becomes:

```
   .append(", my_variable=").append(myVariable)
   .append(", my_other_variable=").append(myOtherVariable)
   .append(", mylowervariable=").append(myLowerVariable) // note the left is already lowercase
   .append(", my_var_with_url=").append(myVarWithURL);
```

The ones on the right are to remain unchanged, while the ones to the left of the equals sign are to be changed, if they contain uppercase characters.

These will be of arbitrary lengths with a varying number of upper case letters. I was thinking I had to do some sort of lookahead but could not get the replacement value to work correctly.

I have the flexibility of being able to do this in IntelliJ or Notepad++, so I can easily perform the \l \L operators to make a replacement value lowercase.

This was my thought process:

in: myLongCamelCasedVariable

re: ([a-z]+)([A-Z]{1})([a-z]+) // repeat grouping for capturing

```
       group 1       group 2        group 3         group 4
my + [ L + ong ] + [ C + amel ] + [ C + ased ] + [ V + ariable ]
```

Is it possible to use a regular expression to effectively capture the various groups of 'text' in the larger text string, and 'loop' over that and apply the output?

Out: $1_\l$2 .... etc

Now I am just stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

*Find What*: `(?:\G(?!\A)|",\h*)\K(\b|[a-z]+)([A-Z]+)(?=\w*=")` 
*Replace With*: `$1_\L$2`
*Match case*: `True`

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|",\h*)` - start matching from the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) a `",` and zero or more horizontal whitespaces (`",\h*`)
- `\K` - remove the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `(\b|[a-z]+)` - Group 1: word boundary or one or more lowercase letters
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 2: one or more uppercase letters
- `(?=\w*=")` - immediately to the right, there must be zero or more word chars followed with a `=` char.

The replacement is `$1_\L$2`: Group 1, `_`, and then lowercased Group 2 value.

See the Notepad++ demo screen:

[image]

Comment: This is close - seems to work in Notepad++. Is there a way to make it work in IntelliJ? It seems to be that the `\K` is not supported.

Comment: @BarryChapman Yes, it is possible, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oLxmTx/1). `(\G(?!\A)|\",\h*)(\b|[a-z]+)([A-Z]+)(?=\w*=\")` is the regex pattern to search for and `$1$2_\L$3` is the replacement pattern.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could match sequences of an uppercase char followed by optional uppercase chars and then optional lowercase chars.

In the replacement use `_` followed by the lowercased match `\L$0`

**Find what:**

```
(?>,\h+[a-z]+|\G(?!^))\K[A-Z][A-Z]*[a-z]*
```

- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `,\h+[a-z]+` Match a comma, 1 or more spaces and 1 or more lowercase chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match but not at the start of the string (so the first part of the alternation has to match first)
- `)` Close atomic group
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[A-Z][A-Z]*[a-z]*` Match an uppercase char followed by optional upper and  lowercase chars

**Replace with:**

```
_\L$0
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bGmQHB/1/)

[image]

---

Without using `\K` you can use 2 capture groups.

```
(?>(, [a-z]+)|\G(?!^))([A-Z][A-Z]*[a-z]*)
```

In the replacement use `$1_\L$2`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using \K, instead using lookbehinds/capture groups?

Comment: @BarryChapman You can use 2 capture groups instead, and use those in the replacement https://regex101.com/r/JVyqbE/1